# Constraints exception handling on weblogic by java hipster

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jhipster, weblogic12c, constraintexception

A project generated by `Jhipster` and deployed on weblogic server. Everythings works fine on weblogic server except constranits exceptions handling.

On tomcat when happen constraints exception is returned status error code 409 correctly but on weblogic return status error code 500, as below, so we cant detect what error has happened

```
with cause = 'weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction' and exception = 'JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction'
```